# SharePoint 2010 Reusable workflow not listed in list in SharePoint Online

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, workflow, reusable-workflow

I have created a Reusable workflow for email notifications.

I have saved this as a template and deployed to production environment

Also i activated the feature, but its not showing in the list when i create a workflow

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i was able to figure out the issue. It seems the Reusable Workflow attaches to the ID of the Content Type and not Name, so i had to create a Content Type in another Environment with the same ID as the one used to create the workflow. And now it appears.